# MICE - How to generate missing values per subset and not whole data.frame

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm trying to analyse some data as part of my dissertation but developing the code is proving impossible (for me)

I'm using a subset of much larger data to develop my code. (not sure how to link the data frame)

```
head(df) 

 well   x   y   time     dist      speed grp
1    1 117 127 15.265 0.000000 0.00000000   1
2    1 118 127 15.303 1.000000 0.06534666   1
3    1 118 127 15.339 0.000000 0.00000000   1
4    1 118 127 15.368 0.000000 0.00000000   1
5    1 119 129 15.403 2.236068 0.14517094   1
6    1 120 129 15.443 1.000000 0.06475426   1

tail(df)

       well   x   y     time     dist        speed grp
664074   24 519 345 6957.419 0.000000 0.0000000000  24
664075   24 519 345 6957.453 0.000000 0.0000000000  24
664076   24 519 345 6957.490 0.000000 0.0000000000  24
664077   24 519 345 6957.529 0.000000 0.0000000000  24
664078   24 518 345 6957.557 1.000000 0.0001437286  24
664079   24 517 344 6957.598 1.414214 0.0002032618  24
```

Essentially, the `X`, `Y` values are from a 24 well plate. After the recording period is complete, the `grp` value will increase by N+1 (just a coincidence that `grp`/`well` ends at the same value).

After each recording period, there is a break in recording and once this has finished, recording resumes. I am currently trying to analyse missing values in my data which I have set to `NA`. To find the missing values, I have used the MICE package using this code (below). I want each `well`, per group, to be analysed separately by the MICE package - instead of all `X`, `Y` coordinates, in one go.

```
for (i in unique(df$well)){

  w1 <- df[df$well==i,]

  for (j in unique(w1$grp)){

    w2 <- w1[w1$grp==j,]  

    temp_df <- mice(data = w2, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5)
  }
}
```

Two things - firstly, the for loops are very slow, and I'm not sure of a way to improve the speed of the script. My initial thought was to create a new column in my d.f, which would fill with N+1 every time the `df$well` values changes, as this would incorporate `df$well` & `df$grp`, but I have been unable to come up with a function to produce this. Once the new column had been generated, I could use one for loop, instead of the two above - which I think would improve the speed?  Secondly, the above script continually re-writes "temp_df", whereas I require it to add to it - I have tried using "rbind" and "apply" which have been suggested from search results but to no avail.

Apologies if this seems relatively straightforward, or has been answered somewhere else. As I said, I am relatively new to R and computing languages in general.

Comment: Try using the `group_by` function in the `dplyr` package. If you make a reproducible example, you may get more help too.

Comment: Instead of `head(df)` it's highly preferred (technically *required*) to use a reproducible data set, such as built-in data, data you create in the script, or `dput` data. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this base R solution using `expand.grid()` and `lapply()`:

```
# DATA FRAME OF ALL COMBINATIONS BETWEEN WELL AND GRP
matches <- expand.grid(unique(df$well), unique(df$grp))

# LIST OF DFs
dfList <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(matches)), function(i) {
              x <- data.frame(df[(df$well == matches$Var1[i]) & 
                                 (df$grp == matches$Var2[i]),])
              temp_df <- mice(data = x, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5)
          })

# ROW BIND LIST OF DFs
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Comment: When running the #long list of DFs script I get the following error message:

'Error in mice(data = x, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5) : 
No missing values found'

There are two options with this, to 'Rerun with Debug' and 'Show Tracebug'. The Tracebug returns:

'4 stop("No missing values found") 
3 mice(data = x, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5) 
2 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1 lapply(1:ncol(output), function(i) {
    x <- data.frame(output[, i])
    temp_df <- mice(data = x, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5)
})'

Due to the error DfList is not generated.

Comment: Following the debug option, one line is highlighted (in bold):

    "function (data, m = 5, method = vector("character", length = ncol(data)), 
  predictorMatrix = (1 - diag(1, ncol(data))), visitSequence = (1:ncol(data))[apply(is.na(data), 
    **2, any)], form = vector("character", length = ncol(data)),** 
  post = vector("character", length = ncol(data)), defaultMethod = c("pmm", 
    "logreg", "polyreg", "polr"), maxit = 5, diagnostics = TRUE, 
  printFlag = TRUE, seed = NA, imputationMethod = NULL, defaultImputationMethod = NULL, 
  data.init = NULL, ...) "

Comment: Apologies for confusion as you had to use all together not as alternative options, so both `mapply()` and `lapply()`. However see edit which simplifies with only `lapply()` used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think the problem arose when the MICE package came across a grp/well combination which did not contain any missing values, so I included an exception within your script. Thanks again, Scott.

Comment: Indeed, add if logic as needed for exceptions. Please accept if answer helped. Also, do recognize this is a vectorized approach, the preferred method in R.